# The generated JSON Web Token is not accepted by Google API Service

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-cloud-platform, jwt, dialogflow-es

I have created a service account and downloaded my JSON Credential on Google Cloud Platform. I need to make REST POST call in .NET to DialogFlow Service API. At this moment, I can do it only with a generated token in PowerShell. Since, I need to do it all from script, I need to generate a JWT to pass as my bearer in my REST call. My Problem is that the generated JWT is not honored by Google.

I get my response in PowerShell based on this [doc page](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/manage-intents) and I replicate sample codes from this [doc page](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#jwt-auth) to create my JWT.

```
public static string GetSignedJwt(string emailClient, string 
dialogueFlowServiceApi, string privateKeyId, string privateKey, string 
jsonPath)
{
    // to get unix time in seconds
    var unixTimeSeconds = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds();

    // start time of Unix system
    var origin = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    // adding milliseconds to reach the current time, it will be used for issueAt time
    var nowDataTime = origin.AddSeconds(unixTimeSeconds);

    // one hour after the current time, it will be used for expiration time
    var oneHourFromNow = nowDataTime.AddSeconds(3600);

    // holder of signed json web token that we will return at the end
    var signedJwt = "";

    try
    {
        // create our payload for Jwt
        var payload = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            {"iss", emailClient},
            {"sub", emailClient},
            {"aud", dialogueFlowServiceApi},
            {"iat", nowDataTime},
            {"exp", oneHourFromNow}
        };

        // create our additional headers
        var extraHeaders = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            {"kid", privateKeyId}
        };

        IJwtAlgorithm algorithm = new HMACSHA256Algorithm();
        IJsonSerializer serializer = new JsonNetSerializer();
        IBase64UrlEncoder urlEncoder = new JwtBase64UrlEncoder();

        IJwtEncoder encoder = new JwtEncoder(algorithm, serializer, urlEncoder);

        signedJwt = encoder.Encode(extraHeaders, payload, privateKey);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);

        // return null if there has been any error
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.WriteLine(signedJwt);
    }

    return signedJwt; 
}
```

Notice that, it is needed to be signed in RSA256 by passing public and private keys, as Google did it in [Java sample snippet](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#jwt-auth), however, my equivalent in .Net gives me only `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` when I use that algorithm:

```
var key = RSA.Create(privateKey);
IJwtAlgorithm algorithm = new RS256Algorithm(null, key);
IJsonSerializer serializer = new JsonNetSerializer();
IBase64UrlEncoder urlEncoder = new JwtBase64UrlEncoder();
IJwtEncoder encoder = new JwtEncoder(algorithm, serializer, urlEncoder);
signedJwt = encoder.Encode(extraHeaders, payload, privateKey);
```

Besides of correct keys, I am using `https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/google.cloud.dialogflow.v2beta1.Intents` as dialogFlow service API key.

I expect it that my generated JWT gets accepted, however it is rejected by Google.

Answer (score 2):

1) You are using the wrong algorithm

Change this line of code:

```
IJwtAlgorithm algorithm = new RS256Algorithm(null, key);
```

To this:

```
IJwtAlgorithm algorithm = new HMACSHA256Algorithm();
```

2) For the JWT headers:

```
var additional_headers = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "kid", privateKeyId },
    { "alg", "RS256" },
    { "typ", "JWT" }
};
```

3) Your JWT Payload does not include a scope. I am not sure which scope you need but here is an example. Add this to the payload before creating the JWT:

```
string scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform";

    var payload = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        {"scope", scope},
        {"iss", emailClient},
        {"sub", emailClient},
        {"aud", dialogueFlowServiceApi},
        {"iat", nowDataTime},
        {"exp", oneHourFromNow}
    };
```

4) For most Google APIs (not all) you also need to exchange the Signed JWT for a Google OAuth Access Token:

```
public static string AuthorizeToken(string token, string auth_url)
{
        var client = new WebClient();

        client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

        var content = new NameValueCollection();

        // Request a "Bearer" access token
        content["assertion"] = token;
        content["grant_type"] = "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer";

        var response = client.UploadValues(auth_url, "POST", content);

        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
}
```

The Authorization URL for above:

```
string auth_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token";
```

Comment: I cannot use "alg" and "typ" in header. I get an error: "An item with the same key has already been added. Key: alg / typ".

Comment: Then AuthorizeToken() method returns "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."

Comment: Also, for AuthorizeToken() method, I tried with provided Urls in my Json key: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth" and "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token", however, I received the same bad request (400) error.

Comment: Where are you getting the Private Key? 400 Bad Request means that something is not formatted correctly, invalid parameters, etc. The Private Key needs to come from a Google service account and not something that you hand created.

Comment: Of course. When I created my service account, a JSON .p12 file has been downloaded. I use the private key from that JSON file. With the same Json file credentials, I cloud pass authorization in POSTMAN and get 200 message. The Problem apparently is creating a valid JWT.

Comment: P12 credentials are deprecated but still work. However, this means that you are probably not using the correct Key ID as that is not part of P12. 400 error means that your credential is not formatted correctly or is missing information. Google verifies your Signed JWT using your public key. That requires sending the correct Private Key ID. The changes that I provided are correct. I took those changes from my code that works, plus I have extensive experience with GCP credentials.

Comment: Here is a link to my article on how to create a signed JWT and exchange for a Google Access Token. This article is in Python but the steps are exactly the same for any language: https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-creating-oauth-access-tokens-for-rest-api-calls/

Comment: The downloaded Json key contains: type, project_id, private_key_id, private_key, client_email, client_id, auth_uri, token_uri, auth_provider_x509_cert_url and client_x509_cert_url.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195484/discussion-between-mohsenne-and-john-hanley).

Comment: I have answered your question. Close this question, Implement the changes that I pointed out in my answer. If you still have problems create a new question and post your new code.